# how can i parse such kind of Data using xml parsing?

Tags: iphone

i want to parse **WCF** type web service how can i parse it?it contains some different kind of data i have used GET method for that.Data looks like this.

### wsdl:definitions

wsp:Policy
wsp:ExactlyOne
wsp:All

### sp:SymmetricBinding

wsp:Policy

### sp:ProtectionToken

wsp:Policy
sp:SecureConversationToken

wsp:Policy
sp:RequireDerivedKeys

sp:BootstrapPolicy
wsp:Policy
sp:SignedParts
sp:Body
sp:Header
sp:Header
sp:Header
sp:Header
sp:Header
sp:Header
sp:EncryptedParts
sp:Body
sp:SymmetricBinding
wsp:Policy
sp:ProtectionToken
wsp:Policy
sp:SpnegoContextToken
wsp:Policy
sp:RequireDerivedKeys
sp:AlgorithmSuite
wsp:Policy
sp:Basic256
sp:Layout
wsp:Policy
sp:Strict
sp:IncludeTimestamp
sp:EncryptSignature
sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody
sp:Wss11
wsp:Policy
sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier
sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial
sp:MustSupportRefThumbprint
sp:MustSupportRefEncryptedKey
sp:Trust10
wsp:Policy
sp:MustSupportIssuedTokens

> alt text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://brismith66.blogspot.com/2010/05/iphone-development-accesing-soap.html

Take Reference From this blog it's really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your given code is in the format of .wsdl file which is api of web service. You have first call the web service using HTTP REST method. After that you will get response of your calling web service, which is in the format of .xml file. After that you will going to parse that xml file using XMLParser class.

Please go through the given link you will get better idea how to be work exactly. 
http://icodeblog.com/2008/11/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-intro-to-soap-web-services/

Comment: NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://abcd.svc?wsdl"];
 NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
 NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
 if(theConnection)
 {
  webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
  NSLog( @"connection established");
 }
 else {
  NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
 }

i have done this way is it ok?what should i do for this?

Comment: i don't have soap message just have one url which is like this:
http://abcd.svc?wsdl then how it is parsed?